# Во время окончания игры у пользователя спрашивали, хочет ли он сыграть снова. Если ответ одобрен, игра должна запуститься снова

Tags: python

Как сделать, чтобы во время окончания игры у пользователя спрашивали, хочет ли он сыграть снова. Если ответ одобрен, игра должна запуститься снова

```py
print('Привіт! Давай Зіграємо в гру Вгадай число.')
print('------------------------------------------')
print('Тобі потрібно буде вгадати число від 1 до 20 ')
comp=randint(1,20)
k=0
user=0
while user!=comp:
    user=int(input('Введіть число:'))
    k+=1
    if user<comp: 
        print('Не вгадав, введи більше число')
    elif user>comp:
        print('Не вгадав, введи менше число')
    else:
        print('Ти вгадав за',k, 'спроб' )
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала создайте какую-то переменную, которая будет решать, если игра будет продолжаться:

```
play = True
```

Затем весь ваш код отступите и перед него добавите (без отступов)

```
while play:
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
    # -------- здесь ваш существующий код, но с отступом ---------
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
```

и за конец вашего кода добавите, тоже с отступом, например

```
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
    # -------- здесь ваш существующий код, но с отступом ---------
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
    if input("Новая игра? [д/н]") == 'н':
        print("Конец.")
        play = False
```

---

*Весь код:*

```
from random import randint

play = True

while play:
    print('Привіт! Давай Зіграємо в гру Вгадай число.') 
    print('------------------------------------------') 
    print('Тобі потрібно буде вгадати число від 1 до 20 ') 
    comp = randint(1,20) 
    k = 0 
    user = 0 
    while user != comp: 
        user = int(input('Введіть число:')) 
        k += 1 
        if user < comp: 
            print('Не вгадав, введи більше число') 
        elif user > comp: 
            print('Не вгадав, введи менше число') 
        else:
            print('Ти вгадав за', k, 'спроб' )
    if input("Новая игра? [д/н] ") == 'н':
        print("Конец.")
        play = False
```

---

*Примечание:*

Я тоже маленько исправил ваш код добавлением пробелов перед и за операторы, чтобы он соответствовал рекомендациям [PEP 8 - руководству по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html).